# Проблема с базой данных и моделями в asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

В моделях у меня находятся 2 модели (User и Song).Связь между моделями один ко многим.Для наглядности я сразу инициализирую у каждого Usera один элемент списка Song

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public List<Song> Songs { get; set; } = new List<Song> { new Song { Name = "Медлячок", Price = 44 } };

    // TODO: Доделать связь с Song
}

public class Song
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

}
```

Проблема в том,что когда я создаю первоначальные данные в БД,то у меня идет все хорошо,видно ,что у первого пользователя 3 Songs как и должно быть[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но затем,когда я получаю в контроллере эту БД,все данные сохраняются,кроме Songs в User.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Остальные песни появятся лишь после загрузки из БД. Как именно это произойдёт, нужно указать: lazy, eager, explicit.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ,Спасибо большое,решило проблему